# QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM error on storage.sync for Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, synchronization

tl;dr: Sync error about QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM, but my item is small, need help figuring out what's wrong with it.

So I'm getting this error on a Google Chrome Extension that I don't think it makes much sense, since what I'm trying to save doesn't get bigger than 400 bytes (serialized, which is bigger than the same in a JSON string), and considering `QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM` is `4096`, it's far from that limit.

Either I'm calculating something wrong (most likely), or I'm doing something wrong (not improbable!).

You can see the [code](https://github.com/emotionLoop/paGen) of my extension and install it from [web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagen/eligfkfpdmeloopcoighgpdgedhnoool)

The part that is important for this problem is the following (CoffeeScript):

```
# Object: Default settings
defaultSettings =
    type: 'single'
    chars: 14
    howmany: 1
    security:
        lowercase: true
        uppercase: true
        special: true
        punctuation: true
        readable: false

# Object: Current settings
paGenSettings = defaultSettings

# Function: Save Settings
saveSettings = (settings, notify) ->
    if validateSettings settings, true
        # Save settings using the Chrome extension storage API. Try sync, fallback to local
            window.chrome.storage.sync.set { settings: settings }, () ->
                if chrome.runtime.lastError && chrome.runtime.lastError.message && chrome.runtime.lastError.message.indexOf( 'MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR' ) != -1
                    window.chrome.storage.local.set { settings: settings }, () ->
                        paGenSettings = settings

                        if notify
                            showNotification window.chrome.i18n.getMessage( 'settingsSaved' )

                        applySettings()

                        true
                else
                    paGenSettings = settings

                    if notify
                        showNotification window.chrome.i18n.getMessage( 'settingsSaved' )

                    applySettings()

                    true
    true
    else
        false

# Function: Get Settings
getSettings = () ->
    # Get settings using the Chrome extension storage API. Try sync, fallback to local
    window.chrome.storage.sync.get 'settings', (items) ->
        if items.settings
            settings = extend( paGenSettings, items.settings)

            if validateSettings settings, false
                paGenSettings = settings

                applySettings()
            true
        else
            window.chrome.storage.local.get 'settings', (items) ->
                if items.settings
                    settings = extend( paGenSettings, items.settings)

                    if validateSettings settings, false
                        paGenSettings = settings
                applySettings()
            true
```

If you inspect it, when you save the settings or generate a password (also saves settings), you'll see the following error popping up:

> Error during storage.set: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded.

I've made it fallback to local storage, but I really want it to sync the settings.

So, if this just won't work, I'll change the get/set code to use a different key/value for each setting, instead of an object, but I don't think it makes much sense, as this sync feature is advertised to support objects (and this one is small), so I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Please reduce your code to a smaller sample, and paste it here, if you expect help. One quick glance shows that you need to brush up your CoffeeScript, because [this line](https://github.com/emotionLoop/paGen/blob/master/code/paGen/popup.coffee#L178) does not do what you think. First, it compiles to `.indexOf(.. !== false)` instead of `.indexOf(...) !== false`. Second, `indexOf` returns numbers only, so this condition is always true. Replace it with `'MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR' in chrome.runtime.lastError.message`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Rob, it really slipped me. I do know it should be -1 instead of false, blame it on coding in several languages :)

I also added the code bit (thanks for that, it does make sense...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I sorted it out.

The main issue was an **"infinite loop"** (n00b) I had because of the **onChanged** listener for **chrome.storage** ( https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#event-onChanged ), where I'd save the settings every time there was a change detected.

I didn't read the documentation carefully enough and thought this was to "listen" for changes in the settings that came, for example, from a sync (but it listens to any change), and since I can get the settings **from** sync, I don't even need it.

**Removing that listener fixed the problem.**

The new version of the extension (1.0.4) is bug-free as far as I'm aware.